# SQL Update secondary table with data from first table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm just learning SQL, so please excuse if this is a bit simple.

I've got an Application form that saves data to 2 tables:  'applications' and 'files'.

The Applications table has a primary key, appID, which is auto-incremental.

On submission, the a new record is created in both tables. My problem is, the 'files' table also has an appID column, which should have the same value as the one in the applications table.

Could someone please help me structure my SQL query to achieve this (or is there a neater way of doing it)?

Thanks

Comment: One you are currently looking is `INSERT` and not `UPDATE` because you want to insert the last generated ID on table `files`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After issuing an `INSERT` statement for the Application table, use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function when populating the `appID` of the files table:

For example:

```
# NULL for appID
INSERT INTO Applications 
VALUES (NULL, "app name") 

# NULL for fileID, LAST_INSERT_ID() for recently inserted appID
INSERT INTO files 
VALUES (NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID(), "file name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
insert into files
(appid, field1, field2, etc)
select appid, value1, value2, etc
from applications
where appid = the one you just inserted.
```